# In a two column div layout right column overwriting left column

Tags: html, css

I am creating a basic portfolio website with a two-column layout. Left column contains navigation and right column would show content.

Here is the HTML and CSS I have:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.jsp">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="portfolio.jsp">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.jsp">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#container {
    max-width: 900px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#nav {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFAD73;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#content {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #73C5FF;
}

li { list-style: none;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rcode74/m8w4yj8o/

The main issue I have my current HTML/CSS is that if browser is made too narrow, navigation column is overlapped by content column. I tried setting `min-width` for navigation div but that resulted in moving the content column to below navigation column when browser is made narrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set a min-width for your #container. The reason it looks like it is overlapping because it is trying to keep the 20-80 for the columns without any min-width restrictions. And since you have content within the left column, it will look like its being overlapped.

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/obna91x1/1/

```
#container {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That is a very simple and elegant solution.